# Javascript functions that validates password (Coderbyte Coding Challenge Simple Password)

Tags: javascript

I am working on Coderbyte coding challenge called Simple Password and the instructions read as following:

Have the function SimplePassword(str) take the str parameter being passed and determine if it passes as a valid password that follows the list of constraints:

1. It must have a capital letter.
2. It must contain at least one number.
3. It must contain a punctuation mark => (. , ! ? : ; )
4. It cannot have the word "password" in the string.
5. It must be longer than 7 characters and shorter than 31 characters.

If all the above constraints are met within the string, the your program should return the string true, otherwise your program should return the string false. For example: if str is "apple!M7" then your program should return "true".

```
Input: "passWord123!!!!"
Output: false

Input: "turkey90AAA!"
Output: true
```

My try

```
function SimplePassword(str) { 

  let result = ""

  for (let i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] === str[i].toUpperCase()) {
      result +=1 
      }

    if (typeof(parseInt(str[i])) === 'number' ) {
      result +=1
      }

    if (str.match(/password/i)) {
       return false
       }

    if (str.length>7 && str.length<31) {
       result +=1
       }

    if (str.match(/.|?|!|:|,|;/)) {
       result +=1
       }
    }
  
   if (result.length === 5) {
      return true
      }
   else {
     return false
   }
   
}
```

My idea was to add '1' to the string result every time a condition is met. If all the 5 conditions are met, the string would have the length 5 and thus the input is correct.

Right now, my second regex seems to be broken and the if-statements are constantly checked. I tried to add break statements to them, but don't know how to 'not evaluate' them anymore after they turned true and added 1 to the string.

Thanks for everyone reading or even helping me fix my code.

Comment: The regex do not need to be in a loop since those check the whole string and not each character.

Comment: `/.|?|!|:|,|;/` can be expressed in a more readable way as `/[.?!:,;]/`.

Comment: Your last three test cases within the `for` loop should not be part of the very one.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: It seems like a codereview question, but in order to be one the code needs to be working as intended...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create booleans instead of using a string? For example;

```
const conditions = { 
  capitals: false,
  numbers: false,
  puncuation: false 
}
```

This way once they've toggled to true, you can constantly set them to true over and over with no negative side effects.

Also, why not check for `if (str.match(/password/i)) return false` outside the loop? Otherwise it has to do this check n times. :)

For the Regex issue stick it into a website like https://regexr.com and you'll see it complain because both `?` and `.` are Regex operators. Instead of searching for the character you're telling Regex to try and perform an invalid search. You would need to escape them using a `\` to search for the actual character. `\.|\?|!|:|,|;`

Comment: I don't understand @PeterSeliger. `/\.|\?|!|:|,|;/.test("passWord123!!!!")` returns `true`. What is the issue? :p

Comment: you are right. I was not careful enough with reading, thus for all the escaping I missed the pipe. sorry for that. I soon will delete my comment about that.

Answer (score 1):

Not as clean as it could be but here it is;

```
function SimplePassword(str) {
    let charCheck = str.length > 7 && str.length < 31;
    let capitalCheck = /[A-Z]/g.test(str);
    let numberCheck = /[0-9]/g.test(str);
    let passwordCheck = !/password/gi.test(str);
    let punctuationCheck = /[.?!:,;]/g.test(str);
    return charCheck && punctuationCheck && capitalCheck && numberCheck && passwordCheck;
}
```

```js
function SimplePassword(str) {
    let charCheck = str.length > 7 && str.length < 31;
    let capitalCheck = /[A-Z]/g.test(str);
    let numberCheck = /[0-9]/g.test(str);
    let passwordCheck = !/password/gi.test(str);
    let punctuationCheck = /[.?!:,;]/g.test(str);
    return charCheck && punctuationCheck && capitalCheck && numberCheck && passwordCheck;
}
function SimplePasswordChecker(str) {
    let charCheck = str.length > 7 && str.length < 31;
    let capitalCheck = /[A-Z]/g.test(str);
    let numberCheck = /[0-9]/g.test(str);
    let passwordCheck = !/password/gi.test(str);
    let punctuationCheck = /[.?!:,;]/g.test(str);
    return {charCheck, punctuationCheck, capitalCheck, numberCheck, passwordCheck};
}

document.querySelector("#poof").onchange=function () {
    document.querySelector("#acceptable").textContent=SimplePassword(this.value)?"true":"false";
    document.querySelector("pre>code").textContent=JSON.stringify(SimplePasswordChecker(this.value),null,2);
};
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" id="poof">
<h5 id="acceptable">Unacceptable</h5>
<pre><code></code></pre>
```

Comment: `SimplePassword` unnecessarily evaluates always every condition instead of exiting the check as fast/soon as possible. Also, there are more capital letters than just A-Z.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// For each condition write a single helper function that
// clearly describes (naming) and evaluates its special case.

// 1) It must have a capital letter.
function doesContainCapitalLetter(str) {
  return str.split('').some(char => (char === char.toUpperCase()));
}

// 2) It must contain at least one number.
function doesContainDigitCharacter(str) {
  return (/\d/).test(str);
}

// 3) It must contain a punctuation mark => (. , ! ? : ; )
function doesContainPunctuationMark(str) {
  return (/[.,!?:;]/).test(str);
}

// 4) It cannot have the word "password" in the string.
function doesNotContainPasswordLiterally(str) {
  return !(/password/i).test(str);
}

// 5) It must be longer than 7 and shorter than 31 characters.
function doesHaveCorrectLength(str) {
  return ((str.length >= 8) && (str.length <= 30));
}


function isValidPassword(str) {

  // - start with the most easy condition to check for.
  let isValid = doesHaveCorrectLength(str);

  // - proceed with checking somehow from the least to the most 
  //   expensive (and/or (un)likely to happen) condition.
  //
  // - make use of the boolean `&&` operator in order to exit the
  //   expression as quick as possible ... e.g. `false && ( ... )`
  //   does not evaluate the right side/expression/term but immediately
  //   returns `false`.

  isValid = isValid && doesNotContainPasswordLiterally(str);
  isValid = isValid && doesContainPunctuationMark(str);
  isValid = isValid && doesContainDigitCharacter(str);
  isValid = isValid && doesContainCapitalLetter(str);

  return isValid;
}


console.log(
  "isValidPassword('passWord123!!!!') ? ",
  isValidPassword('passWord123!!!!')
);

console.log(
  "isValidPassword('turkey90AAA!') ? ",
  isValidPassword('turkey90AAA!')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

The code above of course was just step 1 to the final solution, but it still was close to the OP's original evaluation approach and question about how to keep track of the evaluation parts.

The second example will not use `isValid = isValid && ( ... )` anymore but provide all evaluation step within one expression ... thus it is both very human readable and more easy to maintain ...

```js
function doesContainCapitalLetter(str) {
  return str.split('').some(char => (char === char.toUpperCase()));
}
function doesContainDigitCharacter(str) {
  return (/\d/).test(str);
}
function doesContainPunctuationMark(str) {
  return (/[.,!?:;]/).test(str);
}
function doesNotContainPasswordLiterally(str) {
  return !(/password/i).test(str);
}
function doesHaveCorrectLength(str) {
  return ((str.length >= 8) && (str.length <= 30));
}

function isValidPassword(str) {
  return (
    // - start with the most easy condition to check for.
    //
    doesHaveCorrectLength(str)

    // - proceed with checking somehow from the least to the most 
    //   expensive (and/or (un)likely to happen) condition.
    // - make use of the boolean `&&` operator in order to exit the
    //   expression as quick as possible ... 
    //
    && doesNotContainPasswordLiterally(str)
    && doesContainPunctuationMark(str)
    && doesContainDigitCharacter(str)
    && doesContainCapitalLetter(str)
  );
}


console.log(
  "isValidPassword('passWord123!!!!') ? ",
  isValidPassword('passWord123!!!!')
);

console.log(
  "isValidPassword('turkey90AAA!') ? ",
  isValidPassword('turkey90AAA!')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```